# IndexError: tuple index out of range python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, bs4, pymysql

Вот код

```
import requests
import dateparser
import pymysql.cursors
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock=soup.find('div',{'class':'content-under cclear'})
    item_link=soup.find('meta',{'property':'og:url'})
    item_title=mainblock.find('h1',{'class':'headline'}).text
    item_datetime=mainblock.find('span').text
    item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime,date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    item_text_content_intro=mainblock.find('div',{'class':'content-intro'}).text
    item_text_content=mainblock.find('div',{'class':'content-text js-mediator-article'}).text

    return (item_link['content'],item_title,item_datetime,str.strip(item_text_content_intro,item_text_content))


def main():
    url = 'https://bnews.kz/news/v_otnoshenii_rukovodstva_-narkhoza-_vozbuzhdeno_administrativnoe_delo/'
    (get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
#SQL
#Подключение к базе данных.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='news_portal',
                             charset='utf8',
                             autocommit=True)

url = 'https://bnews.kz/news/v_otnoshenii_rukovodstva_-narkhoza-_vozbuzhdeno_administrativnoe_delo/'
array = get_data(get_html(url))

sql = "insert into todaykz (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`text_content_intro`,`text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor=connection.cursor()

item_link=array[0]
item_title=array[1]
item_datetime=str(array[2])
content_intro =array[3]
text_content=array[4]

cursor.execute(sql,((str(item_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(content_intro),str(text_content))))
print ("Запись в базу данных успешно выполнена.")
```

При вводе в базу данных следующая ошибка:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/bnewskz/bnewskz_parser.py", line 48, in <module>
    text_content=array[4]
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

**Как устранить эту ошибку ?**

Comment: Ну так вы возвращаете кортеж из четырёх элементов, а пытаетесь вытащить несуществующий пятый элемент. Как устранить — или добавьте какой-нибудь пятый элемент к возвращаемому кортежу, или не пытайтесь читать несуществующее

Comment: Я понял.В чем ошибка.Она оказалось в моей не внимательности.Я пытался за инстертить данные в нету таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял.В чем ошибка.Она оказалось в моей не внимательности.Я пытался за инстертить данные в нету таблицу.

Вот правильный код:

```
sql = "insert into bnewskz (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`content_intro`,`text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor=connection.cursor()
```